# What is an "abandoned storyshot"?

Tags: reactjs, storybook, storyshots

Haven't been able to find documentation on this anywhere in Storybook or the Storyshots addon. I am receiving this error in the CI job which runs this script:

`jest --collectCoverage --runInBand`

The error is:

`Found abandoned storyshots. Run jest with -u to remove them`

What is an "abandoned storyshot"? Does that simply mean it's failing or is this a different definition I'm not aware of?